# Finding the set of solutions in the form $v_0+span(v_1,...,v_r)$ with $v_0,...,v_r\in\mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[image]

I have no clue how to approach this problem and have been stuck for some time now. This comes from a past paper.

Comment: For $v_0$, just find some solution that works (e.g. $x=(2, 0, 3, 0, 0)$). The other $v_i$ will span the solution space of the homogeneous system $x_1 + 2x_2 + x_4-x_5 = 0$ and $x_3 - 3x_4 + 5x_5 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this system of equations into an augmented matrix, you'd find that it's already in (reduced) row-echelon form. From here, yoou can identify that the columns corresponding to $x_2$, $x_4$, and $x_5$ do not have pivots, which means you should make them your free variables. From this, we get a parametric solution:
$$\begin{cases}
x_1 = 2 - 2x_2 - x_4 + x_5 \\
x_2 = x_2 \\
x_3 = 3 + 3x_4 - 5x_5 \\
x_3 = x_3 \\
x_4 = x_4 \
x_5 = x_5
\end{cases} \quad \quad x_2, x_4,x_5 \in \Bbb{R}.$$
This can be turned into a vector equation:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 - 2x_2 - x_4 + x_5 \\ x_2 \\ 3 + 3x_4 - 5x_5 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Now, collect the constant terms, and each of the $x_i$ terms (the free ones, i.e. $i=2,4,5$) in their own vector:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -2x_2 \\ x_2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -x_4 \\ 0 \\ 3x_4 \\ x_4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} x_5 \\ 0 \\ -5x_5 \\ 0 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix}.$$
If we factor these $x_i$s from their respective vectors, we get what you need:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + x_2\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + x_4\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + x_5\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -5 \\ 0 \\  1\end{pmatrix}.$$
That is,
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5\end{pmatrix} \in \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -5 \\ 0 \\  1\end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$